# how to get all pages in WordPress when WPML plugin is activated?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am developing WordPress site and in that I need a drop-down where I can load all list of pages available.

Here is the code that does it for me

```
$args = array(
    'sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'sort_column' => 'post_title',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$pages = get_pages($args);
```

But when [WPML](https://wpml.org/) plugin is activated and I have pages in different languages too. so above code only returns list of pages for one language either English or Italian.

I tired to find a way to search in the tickets of WPML forum but they all are deprecated functions and now need a solution to that.
I tired with https://wpml.org/forums/topic/show-all-pages-wp_list_pages/ url but no luck.

Any good way how can I fix that ?

Any information on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research I found a proper solution. 
Here is the code that fetch all the pages by activate languages.

```
$all_pages = array();

$languages = apply_filters( 'wpml_active_languages', NULL, array( 'skip_missing' => 0));

foreach( (array) $languages as $lang ) {
    /* change language */
    do_action( 'wpml_switch_language', $lang['code'] );
    /* building query */
    $posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'sort_order' => 'ASC',
        'sort_column' => 'post_title',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );
    $posts = $posts->posts;
    foreach( (array) $posts as $post ) {
        $all_pages[esc_url(get_page_link($post->ID))] = $post->post_title;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are the king

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `wpml_switch_language` actions to specify which language to query.

```php
do_action( "wpml_switch_language", "de" ); // To switch to a specific language
do_action( "wpml_switch_language", "all" ); // To query everything and not a specific language

// Run the query
new \WP_Query();

do_action( "wpml_switch_language", null ); // Returns to the original language
```

See for https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_switch_language/ more details